# Set property of sibling instance components in Angular 2

Tags: angular

This is a basic Angular question regarding the relationship between components, though so far I couldn't understand it.
I have a child and a parent component. I want to show all of the instances of the child components, unless one of the child components was clicked (and in case one was clicked - hide everything else).

this is the child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, SimpleChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from './customer.model';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-detail',
  templateUrl: './customer-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-detail.component.css']
})
export class CustomerDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('customer') customer : Customer;
  @ViewChild('wrapperDiv') wrapperDiv: ElementRef;
  @Output() selected = new EventEmitter<CustomerDetailComponent>();

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  customerFormOnClick(){
    this.selected.emit(this);
  }

}
```

this is the parent HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="!initialized" class="loading">Loading&#8230;</div>
<app-customer-detail *ngFor="let c of customers" (selected)="onCustomerSelected($event)" [customer]="c"></app-customer-detail>
```

And this is the parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from '../customer-list/customer-detail/customer.model';
import { WebApiObservableService } from '../shared/web-api.service';
import * as GLOBALS from '../globals';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-list',
  templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.css']
})
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit {
  initialized: boolean = false;
  customers: Customer[] = [];

  @Input('selectedCustomer') selectedCustomer : Customer;
  url = environment.titlesUrl;
  body = environment.titlesBody;

  constructor(private customersWebService : WebApiObservableService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customersWebService.createService(this.url, this.body)
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.initialized = true;
          this.customers = [];
          result.titles.forEach(element => {
            var customer = new Customer(element.mainloanerdetails, element.iconflag, element.shortname);
            this.customers.push(customer);
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
  }

  ngOnChanges(){

  }

  onCustomerSelected($event){
    var count = 0
    this.customers.forEach(element => {
      if (element != $event.customer){
        // NOW, HERE I HAVE THE CHILD COMPONENET, BUT I DON'T WANT TO fadeOut() IT, I WANT TO fadeOut() THE ELEMENT (BUT THE ELEMENT IS A CUSTOMER, NOT AN ELEMENTREF
        //$($event.wrapperDiv.nativeElement).fadeOut()
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess I could add a property to Customer model indicating if it should be shown or not, but is that the right approach?! Should the model contain information about its' view, styling etc?

Comment: if you don't want to add styling property to your model, you can pass index property of ngFor directive as input parameter to detail component. *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [detailIndex]="i"